# Custom view in Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, view

If i want to create custom view
and i want to pass custom type to this from xml
what should i do ?

*for example:*

```
class Custom(@JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

this is my custom view class
how i can pass my custom type to it through XML ?

```
<Custom
...
data=@{viewmodel.data}
/>
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the extensive documentation on how to setup custom attributes and provide data to the view: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view